# Create an update for an extension in Magento

Tags: magento

My question is about creating update packages for a custom module extension that I have made.

So far I have been able to export mu module by using the "create package extension" function and installing the module on another Magento using the "Direct package file upload" method in Magento connect.

But when I make a newer version of the module, by chancing some code in the modules PHP files, package the extension and try to upload to Magento using "Direct package file upload" method, it says it can't, upload the module because the files already exists.

I have remembered to change the version number in the config.xml file, and I have made an update script for the database. But other than that I can't figure out how to proceed, and I have been unable to find documentation, for how to make extensions upgrades elsewhere.

I hope you will be able to give me a little help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

File already exists means you've already uploaded an update with that version number.

You can't trick the package ;)

You must repackage on the backend with a new version number.  Just changing the package.xml doesn't work ;) Trust me.. I've tried for a quick work around.

More here at the FAQ: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/magento_connect_faq

Also new packaging info here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/new_developer/